# Problems installing Hydro on Pi3 (yaml.constructor)

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm following the step-by-step instruction:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20Hydro%20on%20RaspberryPi

Step:

```
$ rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only > hydro-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
```

returns error:

```
 File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 452, in construct_undefined
    node.start_mark)
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/str'
  in "<string>", line 5773, column 28:
        </package>\n", ar_sys: !!python/str "<?xml version=\"1. ..
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix that?

Thanks
Rabiato

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368148/problems-installing-hydro-on-pi3-(yaml.constructor)/) by [Rabiato](https://answers.ros.org/users/66022/rabiato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-21**:
Do you have a specific reason to want to install ROS Hydro? It's been EOL for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner and want to work with the book "Learning ROS for Robotics Programming" which uses Hydro. However, I gave it a thought and guess it should work with later versions too.
I'm currently installing Melodic w/ instruction and it looks like it is working:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Melodic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

Thanks, I guess I close the question since it's a wast to go back in time.

---

Originally posted by [Rabiato](https://answers.ros.org/users/66022/rabiato/) with karma: 16 on 2020-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0